# Scala Streams and their stack memory usage

Tags: scala, stream

Suppose, I have a recursively-defined `Stream`: e.g.

```
def from(n:Int):Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(n, from(n+1))
```

I guess it requires constant stack memory. Is it correct? Is it correct for any recursively-defined `stream`? Can you think of any recursively-defined `stream` example, which uses non-constant stack memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking whether *accessing* the stream requires constant stack memory?

If so the answer is yes: `apply` for `Stream`s is defined in terms of `drop` (the definition is in [`LinearSeqOptimized`](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/collection/LinearSeqOptimized.scala#L1)), and `drop` is tail-recursive, so is compiled into a `while` loop.

That makes `drop` essentially look as follows:

```
def drop(n: Int) : Stream[A] = {
  var _this = this
  var _n = n

  while(!(_n <= 0 || _this.isEmpty)) {
    _this = _this.tail
    _n = _n - 1
  }
  _this
}
```

So the only increase in stack size can come from the call to `_this.tail`. In your definition of `from`, that call will never increase the stack: all it does is build an instance of `Stream.cons` (since the recursive call is not actually evaluated at that point).